# Neo4j in Github actions - connection refused

Tags: neo4j, github-actions

I've not had much luck adding Neo4j to Github actions. Here's what I've got in the Yaml file which relates to Neo4j:

```
services:
      neo4j:
        image: neo4j:5.5.0
        ports:
          - 7474:7474
          - 7687:7687
        env:
          NEO4J_USERNAME: "neo4j"
          NEO4J_PASSWORD: "neo4j"
          NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address: "localhost:7474"
          NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: "localhost:7687"
```

The result is always:

```
/home/runner/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2@myapp/gems/neo4j-ruby-driver-4.4.3/ruby/neo4j/driver/internal/async/connection/channel_connector_impl.rb:34:in `rescue in connect': Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7687 (Neo4j::Driver::Exceptions::ServiceUnavailableException)
```

As part of the setup I'm also copying a config. file into my Rails application which sets the correct port, though I'm using the default.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Have you tested the same image locally? Does it work?

Comment: No, I have not. Attempting to replicate the Github setup locally is something I'll eventually have to get around to doing, but there has not been the opportunity yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since Neo4j 5.3, the default min length requirement for password is 8 characters. Have you tried a longer password?
If that's not the issue, please grab the container logs and share them here.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, "neo4j" is the default password, so I'd expect to be able to connect using that. Wouldn't the minimum be for setting another password other than the default?
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/set-initial-password/

Comment: I've now got the logs, using jwalton/gh-docker-logs@v2. It turns out that I was using NEO4J_USERNAME etc. instead of NEO4J_AUTH. That solves the connection issue; now I have to work out how to enable APOC, but that's another matter. ;-)

Comment: you've got the NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS envvar shortcut for that

Comment: So I discovered (see below). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After checking the logs as suggested above the new configuration I have is as follows; this is working as expected:

```
        env:
          NEO4J_AUTH: none
          NEO4J_server.http.advertised_address: "localhost:7474"
          NEO4J_server.bolt.advertised_address: "localhost:7687"
          NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: "apoc.*"
          NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled: true
          NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled: true
          NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config: true
          NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS: '["apoc"]'
```

...and under "steps":

```
      - name: Dump docker logs on failure
        if: failure()
        uses: jwalton/gh-docker-logs@v2
```